# What is a "Plain" or "Simple" JAR File

Tags: java, jar

I read the terms "plain JAR"/"simple JAR" in the Java docs. What is a "plain" or "simple" JAR file. Does that mean the JAR only contains Java classes? If a JAR contains ".dll" and ".xml" files, it cannot be considered a plain JAR file correct?

**EDIT:** Here is the link for the J2EE docs where these terms are referenced.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/libraries.html

Comment: Whenever you quote from an online resource, please provide links.

Comment: [Here is a link for Eclipse users that may apply indirectly to you](http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/javabasics/jar/eclipse.xhtml)

Comment: as per the link, "simple" JAR is one that ain't any of: standalone EJB module, standalone Web application module, multiple EJB modules packaged in an Enterprise Application, multiple Web application modules package in an Enterprise Application; if the app is not packaged as any of those, then the JAR is "plain".

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that a non-simple JAR file is actually one of the specializations:

- WAR (Web Application Archive)
- EAR (Enterprise Application Archive)
- RAR (Resource Adapter Module)

All of these share the format of .jar files, but add special semantics on top.

Comment: +(int)(PI/3) - since actually, you're almost right - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263381/what-is-a-plain-or-simple-jar-file#comment54487702_33263381 (it's put straightly in the Oracle link provided by OP)

Answer (score 0):

A **JAR** (Java ARchive) file is a file that contains the class, image, and sound files for a Java application or applet gathered into a single file and possibly compressed. When a programmer gets a Java program development kit, a small program or utility called "jar" is included.

Comment: I think OP is more interested in the terminology of *plain* and *simple*. I think he knows, what a JAR is.